# Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got '{'

Tags: python-3.x

I am new to python.

my objective :- download csv from website
                convert csv to Json

I have converted all csv rows as per my json requirement, but still end result is not as i expected.

here is my code

```
 import urllib.request
 import os
 import csv
 import json
 url = 'http://hmt-sanctions.s3.amazonaws.com/sanctionsconlist.csv'
 urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,'hmtc.csv')
 csvfile = open('hmtc.csv', 'r')
 jsonfile = open('hmtc.json', 'w')
 csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
 next(csvreader)
 header = next(csvreader)
 reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, header)
 for row in reader:
     json.dump(row,jsonfile)
     jsonfile.write('\n')
```

but the json file i get has no starting '[' and ending ']' and also after every entry there should be  } ',' { which is also missing.

I know it is a very basic and substandard code but please help me.

Comment: You should convert the entire CSV to a single JSON, instead of each row individually. Maybe even `json.dump(reader, jsonfile)` works.

Comment: Apparently that doesn't work, but `json.dump(list(reader), jsonfile)` could work. However, it is not the best solution if the input is large, because it first reads it all into memory at once before writing out to JSON again. I suggest you manually write the enclosing `[]` and the `,` to the JSON file (as you do with the `\n`).

Comment: @Rahul Shukla read all your csv data rows and keep appending then to a list, and when done reading the csv then json.`dumps` the list made

Comment: @mkrieger1 thank u for the suggestion

Comment: @tkhurana96 i will try your method also